# Custom wpf bootstrap wix bundle unable to install the msi package after installing redistributables

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I'm writing the custom wpf bootstrap application which installs the .Net framework and redistributables (downloading and installing) but it is skipping the msi package for installation.

Wix code:

[image: Wix bundle code] Please kindly go through the above wix bundle code

Below is the event for to download the redist and install i have added

```
void Bootstrapper_ResolveSource(object sender, ResolveSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.DownloadSource))
            {
                e.Result = Result.Download;
                this.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "download source is not empty "+e.DownloadSource);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Result = Result.Continue;
            }
        }
```

Currently i'm using wix 3.10 version.

Log file :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-iKQhr12DRmVjZzbDE0US1vcm8

Alternate link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-iKQhr12DRmVjZzbDE0US1vcm8/view

Kindly provide your valuable help for further step.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From your log:

> Detected package: xyz, state: Present, cached: None

Windows Installer detects that the package is already installed.

Comment: No xyz.msi package is added to wix bundle so it will carry msi with wix bundle and remaining vcredit wil be downloading over net and installs.I had checked in start menu and control panel there is no trace's of installation of xyz.msi